# Laravel Service provider and Service Container

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-service-container

In Laravel to access query, we use `DB` facades

```
DB::select()
```

from alanstorm website http://alanstorm.com/binding_objects_as_laravel_services I learned that `DB` facade use `callstatic` method that lead to `DB::app['db']->select()`. `app` is the Laravel service container object which all the services are bound into it. I use `var_dump` PHP method `var_dump(app['db'])` and I can see that the service container returns an `Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager` object. from `DatabaseManager` class that implement `ConnectionResolverInterface`. I don't see the select method defined there. I want to ask how `app['db']` can get access to select method.

Comment: Long story short it eventually returns [https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Connection.html](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Connection.html)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy i figure it out sir that the query syntax came from https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Connection.html but i need and explanation how DatabaseManager object from app['db'] can use Connection class method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DatabaseManager` class implements `__call()` method
if you call a method on that class that doesn't exist it's immediately passed as an argument to `__call()`, which is one of php's magic [methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call).

that calls connection class with the method you passed.

here's the method implementation in Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager

```
/**
 * Dynamically pass methods to the default connection.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array   $parameters
 * @return mixed
 */
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    return $this->connection()->$method(...$parameters);
}
```

Comment: i'm getting clearer sir thanks to you but i have one more question, when i var_dump app['db']->connection() it returning mysqlconnection object. in databasemanager class there is connection method with $name paramater. how app['db']->connection() can return mysql type connection when i never set databasemanager connection method with mysql type before. thnk u sir

Comment: in `connection()` method if you didn't pass a name the method gets the default connection specified in the `.env` file or the `config/database.php` file. which in this case mysql type... dig deeper into the source code and you'll understand.